# Using asp webservice with android

Tags: java, android, asp.net, web-services, api

I'm trying to access this link for web service via android .

but I don't know what is library or jar files should using to do this .

I have used soap but not working will

here is link is : 
    http://ictfox.com/demo/Hafil_Updates/Login_Check.aspx?UserLogin=Demo&Password=Demo

Comment: this is not a soap api. you only get true back...

Comment: You need to make a bigger effort on your research!!!! check here: http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/83/

Comment: this example shows gerneral info about webservice , i need some way to call and get asp webservice on android

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use  **DefaultHttpClient** android api to send GET request as you shown.

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
 URI webserv = new URI(" http://ictfox.com/demo/Hafil_Updates/Login_Check.aspx?UserLogin=Demo&Password=Demo");
  request.setURI(webserv);
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
  String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Answer (score -1):

this is tutorial show you how to call android application webservice using protocol soap

http://android.programmerguru.com/how-to-call-asp-net-web-service-in-android/

Comment: You have to explain your little more how your solution works.